# python - read pdf ignoring header and footer

Tags: python, pdf, pymupdf

I have a pdf file that I am reading using pymupdf using the below syntax.

```py
import fitz  # this is pymupdf

with fitz.open('file.pdf') as doc:

    text = ""
    for page in doc:
        text += page.getText()
```

Is there a way to ignore the header and footer while reading it?

I tried converting pdf to docx as it is easier to remove headers, but the pdf file I am working on is getting reformatted when I convert it to docx.

Is there any way pymupdf does this during the read?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation has a page dedicated to this problem.

1. Define rectangle that omits the header
2. Use page.get_textbox(rect) method.

Source: https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF-Utilities/tree/master/textbox-extraction#2-pageget_textboxrect

The generic solution that works for most pdf libraries is to

1. check for the size of the header/footer section in your pdf files
2. loop for each text in the document and check it's vertical position

Answer (score 0):

As the [official document](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page.html#Page.get_text) says, you can use the `clip` argument to do it:

```py
doc = fitz.open(fname)
page = doc[0]
rect = page.rect
height = 50
clip = fitz.Rect(0, height, rect.width, rect.height-height)
text = page.get_text(clip=clip)
```