# Remove PDF header and footer with PyPDF2

Tags: python, pypdf, headerfooter

I am using the library PyPDF2 to read pdf files and convert to text format. There are a number of PDF files, and using the [following code](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/user/extract-text.html):

```
def visitor_body(text, cm, tm, fontDict, fontSize):
    y = tm[5]
    if y > 50 and y < 720:
        parts.append(text)
```

Works for some pdf files but not others. Is there a way to extract header and footer size of each pdf when first read, and use that instead of constants 50 and 720? I noted some solutions for other libraries exist, like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68082761/python-read-pdf-ignoring-header-and-footer) but I am interested to learn this about PyPDF2.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

# Replace below file name with multiple different files
reader = PdfReader("GeoBase_NHNC1_Data_Model_UML_EN.pdf")

page = reader.pages[3]

parts = []


def visitor_body(text, cm, tm, fontDict, fontSize):
    y = tm[5]
    if y > 50 and y < 720:
        parts.append(text)


page.extract_text(visitor_text=visitor_body)
text_body = "".join(parts)

print(text_body)
```

Comment: @KJ thanks for the answer, could you clarify footer be line 24 + line 30 from right to left with an example?